# adding new comment in database for a post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating a forum application in mvc3...

I have a link called Add New Comment on Post page where user can add the comments for that post... for creating new comment i have written following code....

```
 public ActionResult Addnew(int id)
    {
        Answer ans = new Answer();
        ans.QuestionQId = id;

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Addnew(Answer ans,int id)
    {

        _db.Answers.Add(ans);
        _db.SaveChanges();
           return View("Details");
    }
```

but it is giving mean error whenever i try to save the code as follows:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity

I have two different table Question{id(pk), Question} and Answer{id(pk), ans, Qid(fk)}

All i want to do is While adding the comment for a perticular question, its Qid will be stored in answer database .....

Help me!!

View Related --

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <fieldset> 
     <legend>Answer</legend> 
     <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AId)
    </div> 
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AId) 
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ans)
    </div> 
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ans) 
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ans)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionQId)
    </div> <div class="display-field">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.QuestionQId)
    </div> 
}
```

Comment: the error you get is on save right? then can you show the Action result responsible for save...

Comment: Did you check whether the `ans` parameter is null?

Comment: @Eranga: yes it is showing me ans as null and giving me error over there...but i dont know how to resolve it

Comment: Can you post the `Addnew` view(code inside `using(var for = BeginForm`)

Comment: @Eranga: hey i need to break the code since itnot allowing meto paste the whole code

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Answer</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AId)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AId)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ans)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ans)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ans)</div>

Comment: <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionQId)</div>
         <div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.QuestionQId)</div>
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not passing the Answer object to the view, may caused the problem. have you tried following

```
public ActionResult Addnew(int id)
    {
        Answer ans = new Answer();
        ans.QuestionQId = id;

        return View(ans);
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged the solution and checked whether the Answer object in post method is null or not?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.ValidationSummary(true) <fieldset> <legend>Answer</legend> <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AId)</div> <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AId) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AId)</div> <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ans)</div> <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ans) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ans)</div>

Comment: <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionQId)</div> <div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.QuestionQId)</div> }

Comment: Hey where is the submit button?? haven't you used any or didn't put in the comment? can you update the question with the full code of the view

Comment: Its after my Begin form block as
  
           <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
        </p>

Comment: thank you for allyour help 
I was able to Solve and can view all my comments of selected Question:)

Answer (score 0):

is it in your route define parameter for your controller?
may be this is your problem!